# RuntimeError: Model class doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS for Django OAuth Toolkit

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0

I want to access the models that are used by Django OAUTH Toolkit so I can periodically delete old tokens from the database. I thought I'd just import them:

```
from oauth2_provider.management.commands.cleartokens import Command
from oauth2_provider.models import AccessToken
Command.handle()
```

However when I try to run this file in the command line I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\db_cleanup.py", line 5, in <module>
    from oauth2_provider.models import AccessToken
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\gsm-django\lib\site-packages\oauth2_provider\models.py", line 178, in <module>
    class Application(AbstractApplication):
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\gsm-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 95, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class oauth2_provider.models.Application doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

I tried adding `oauth2_provider.models.Application` to my installed apps in my settings file as well but to no avail:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'api',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'oauth2_provider.models.Application',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'graphene_django',
    'corsheaders',
]
```

I added `app_label` to the `Application` class it mentions as well, but that does not work either.

Comment: What is your `Django` version? If you are using [this package](https://github.com/caffeinehit/django-oauth2-provider) then please note that it was last updated 5 years ago and might not be compatible with the newest `Django` version.

Comment: Specially the change to `app_label` starting in `Django 2.0` might break older apps. Read more about https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28691 and in related tickets.

Comment: I'm using Django 2.1, maybe youre right and it's an incompatibility issue

Comment: My bad! I'm actually using this package: https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit that is compatible with django 2.0

Comment: I think I may have located the problem, I'm using IntelliJ and when I run the file from the console in IntelliJ I get the error: `pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (Django 1.11.16 (c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('django>=2.0'), {'django-oauth-toolkit'})` it seems django is outdated in IntelliJ or something. As opposed to when I run it from my CLI

Comment: nvm still not working

Comment: I had the same issue. I closed the terminal and opened in new terminal of IntelliJ and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [django-oauth2-provider docs](https://django-oauth2-provider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#add-oauth2-provider-to-installed-apps) (I assume this is the correct library; I had to guess since I did not find a link in your question), it says there:

> Add OAuth2 Provider to INSTALLED_APPS
>
> ```
> INSTALLED_APPS = (
>     # ...
>     'provider',
>     'provider.oauth2',
> )
> ```

But I noticed that your code in the question has something else:

```
'oauth2_provider',
'oauth2_provider.models.Application',
```

Have you tried what the docs suggest? Does that work for you?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I added those but still no success!

Comment: @CharlesSmith just to be clear: have you just added these 2 new app names or have you also removed the 2 app names that you had there? Because I think you need to remove the 2 names you had there.

Comment: I have also removed them

Comment: @CharlesSmith Is the error message still the same or different now?

Comment: the message is the same!

Comment: Its saying the class im trying to import isn't in installed apps, could this problem be caused by the fact that it's not apart of my project but a an external library?